# Private Static Members inside a Static Class... Good idea?

Tags: c#, static

I created a static class with a private static member inside of it. That private static member is accessible to all of my static class methods.

This happened while I wasn't really paying attention, but then I realized what I had done, and that - interestingly enough - it seems to be working fine in my application. Nonetheless, it seemed like a silly thing to do (coming from C++), so I have been searching around trying to find more info on whether this is really supposed to be possible and/or if it is considered good or bad practice, but I haven't really been able to find anything at all about creating private static members inside a static class in C#.

It almost seems like static methods inside my static class have an implicit "this" variable (since I'm also able to call other methods without fully qualifying them with the class name), which feels a be peculiar to me.

I was hoping some of you might have some thoughts about whether this is a good idea or not, and why C# makes this possible at all.

The class:

```
public static class ControlHighlighter
{
    private static Panel highlightPanel = null;

    public static void Highlight(Control control = null, int thickness = 1)
    {
        RemoveHighlight();

        if (control != null)
        {
            if (control.Parent != null)
            {
                highlightPanel = new Panel();
                control.Parent.Controls.Add(highlightPanel);
                highlightPanel.Location = new Point(control.Location.X - thickness,
                                                    control.Location.Y - thickness);
                highlightPanel.Size = new Size(control.Size.Width + (2 * thickness),
                                               control.Size.Height + (2 * thickness));
                highlightPanel.SendToBack();
                highlightPanel.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void RemoveHighlight()
    {
        if (highlightPanel != null)
        {
            highlightPanel.Dispose();
            highlightPanel = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So why do you think it shouldn't be possible to do that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review and belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Not really sure you need to store a reference to this panel, as it will be in the Control list of the object, so just find it. Consider using extensions and not using private static member.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, there's nothing wrong with having private static members in static classes (or even in non-static classes). They do pose some potential problems, though: when your application is multithreaded, these static members are shared across all threads so you have to apply locking around them.

Since you never know if you need to make your application multithreaded, it's best to keep the number of static variables to a minimum - all static variables shared between threads must be protected through locks or other synchronization primitives. It's far easier to do this kind of work ahead of time than patching problems later on.

However, in your specific example, you're putting a UI control in a static variable - this is something I'd definitely advise against. UI controls live on the UI thread and must be properly invoked when called from a different thread. Threading issues aside, putting a control in a static variable is a recipe for trouble - the static variable requires careful bookeeping to clean up - if the form hosting the control goes away, the static reference will still keep it in memory (because the control cannot go away). This can lead to all kinds of hard-to-find problems.

If you're not familiar with `static` in C#, I recommend reading [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691162%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more detail.

Comment: +1 - I didn't even consider the controls being rooted.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about UI controls, that's helpful info.

Comment: @jramm I'm glad it's useful. To understand about threading and UI, read about `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke`. The TL;DR of it is that you must call controls on the UI thread - all other threads must marshal the call to the UI thread through those functions.

Answer (score 3):

> It almost seems like static methods inside my static class have an implicit "this" variable

Correct. A `static` class cannot be instantiated. Because there is no instance variable, you access the members of a `static` class by using the class name itself. When you're within the scope of the `static` class, accessing the `static` members within does not require prefixing it with an instance variable (`this`).

> I was hoping some of you might have some thoughts about whether this is a good idea or not

Really .. the only issue is in a multi-threaded environment. Since this class and its data will be shared across threads (a single instance ..) then you'll need to synchronize around its access. In general, a `static` class should avoid maintaining state for this very reason.

Comment: I think I get what you're trying to say, but talking about instances of, and this references in, a static class might be a bit confusing.

Comment: I mentioned it because that was part of the OP's question - hence the quotes. If thats the reason for the downvote I would be happy to rephrase.

Comment: My main problem is with "A static class only has a single instance"; there's not an actual instance of the class. People might get confused reading that, and then wonder what this singleton thing is everyone's talking about.

Comment: I am unsure how to rephrase that .. does my edit suit?

Comment: Nevermind - I reverted it. If you can suggest a different phrasing of that I will happily update my answer.

Comment: His assumption is sort of correct, in that instances infer "this" for members when compiled, where as static methods infer the class reference. I would completely remove the "A static class only has a single instance" part, as it's not correct.

Comment: Better? ....... (I ripped some of it from MSDN.. clearly my way of expressing what I mean requires my over-the-top hand gestures while doing so).